# Vue.js / webpack: how do I clear out old bundle main-*.js files when hot-reload transpiles them?

Tags: javascript, django, webpack, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js to make an SPA application with Django and I transpile, uglify, and bundle the code using webpack (specifically `webpack-simple` from `vue-cli` setup).

I use the following to "watch" and hot-reload the code:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch
```

The problem is every time I change the code and it gets built it generates a new bundle .js file and updates `webpack-stats.json` to point to that one, but doesn't delete the old ones. How do I have it delete the old (useless) files?

`webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')


function resolve (dir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, dir)
}

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,

    // entry point of our app. 
    // assets/js/index.js should require other js modules and dependencies it needs
    entry: './src/main', 

    output: {
            path: path.resolve('./static/bundles/'),
            filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
    },

    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            },
            sourceMap: true
        }),
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}, // to transform JSX into JS
            {test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue-loader'}

        ],
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
            '@': resolve('src')
        }
    },
}
```

`webpack-stats.json`:

```
{  
   "status":"done",
   "chunks":{  
      "main":[  
         {  
            "name":"main-faa72a69b29c1decd182.js",
            "path":"/Users/me/Code/projectname/static/bundles/main-faa72a69b29c1decd182.js"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Also what's a good way to add this to git/source control? Otherwise it changes everytime and I have to add it like so:

```
$ git add static/bundles/main-XXXXX.js -f
```

which gets annoying.

Any pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need `clean-webpack-plugin` [github link](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin)
First install it:

```
npm i clean-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Then in webpack.config.js add these lines(I have added comments the lines I added):

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin'); // require clean-webpack-plugin

function resolve (dir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, dir)
}

// the path(s) that should be cleaned
let pathsToClean = [
    path.resolve('./static/bundles/'),  // same as output path
]

// the clean options to use
let cleanOptions = {
    root: __dirname,
    exclude:  [],  // add files you wanna exclude here
    verbose:  true,
    dry:      false
}

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,

    // entry point of our app. 
    // assets/js/index.js should require other js modules and dependencies it needs
    entry: './src/main', 

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./static/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
    },

    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean, cleanOptions),  // add clean-webpack to plugins
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            },
            sourceMap: true
        }),
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}, // to transform JSX into JS
            {test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue-loader'}

        ],
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
            '@': resolve('src')
        }
    },
}
```

And that's it, now every time you will run `npm run build`, the plugin will delete the `static/bundles/` folder then build, so all your previous files will get removed, only new files will be there. It won't remove old files while watching with `npm run watch`

Answer (score 1):

The current latest version does not need any options passed in for most cases. Consult the documentation for more specifics https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-webpack-plugin

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const webpackConfig = {
    plugins: [
        /**
         * All files inside webpack's output.path directory will be removed once, but the
         * directory itself will not be. If using webpack 4+'s default configuration,
         * everything under <PROJECT_DIR>/dist/ will be removed.
         * Use cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns to override this behavior.
         *
         * During rebuilds, all webpack assets that are not used anymore
         * will be removed automatically.
         *
         * See `Options and Defaults` for information
         */
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust webpack so a new bundle is only being created when actually building for production.

From the webpack-simple vue-cli template, you'll see that uglifying and minifying only take place when it is set to a production env, not a dev env:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Comment: I don't think this solves what he is asking. I believe the main-.js files are generated on 'watch'. He wants to auto delete all the old files in the bundle folder